# How to combine two yolov3 models for object detection?

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

We have two yolov3-tiny models for license plate detection.The first yolov3-tiny model detecting licence plate on cars and cropping it for the second yolov3-tiny model, then should send these output cropped images to the second yolov3-tiny model as input images. The second yolov3-tiny model should have receive these cropped images as input for detecting country region.
We have a problem with combining two models. Any advice and help is appreciated.
The code below:

```
# This code is written at BigVision LLC. It is based on the OpenCV project. It is subject to the license terms in the LICENSE file found in this distribution and at http://opencv.org/license.html

# Usage example:  python3 object_detection_yolo.py --video=run.mp4
#                 python3 object_detection_yolo.py --image=bird.jpg

import cv2 as cv
import argparse
import sys
import numpy as np
import os.path

# Initialize the parameters
confThreshold = 0.5  #Confidence threshold
nmsThreshold = 0.4   #Non-maximum suppression threshold
inpWidth = 608       #Width of network's input image
inpHeight = 608      #Height of network's input image

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Object Detection using YOLO in OPENCV')
parser.add_argument('--image', help='Path to image file.')
parser.add_argument('--video', help='Path to video file.')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Load names of classes
classesFile = "obj.names"
classes = None
with open(classesFile, 'rt') as f:
    classes = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

# Load names of classes
classesFile1 = "obj1.names"
classes1 = None
with open(classesFile1, 'rt') as f:
    classes1 = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

# Give the configuration and weight files for the model and load the network using them.
modelConfiguration = "yolov3-tiny_obj.cfg"
modelWeights = "yolov3-tiny_obj_final.weights"

# Give the configuration and weight files for the model and load the network using them.
modelConfiguration1 = "yolov3-tiny_obj1.cfg"
modelWeights1 = "yolov3-tiny_obj_final1.weights"

net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)

net1 = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration1, modelWeights1)
net1.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net1.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)

# Get the names of the output layers
def getOutputsNames(net):
    # Get the names of all the layers in the network
    layersNames = net.getLayerNames()
    # Get the names of the output layers, i.e. the layers with unconnected outputs
    return [layersNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
#====================================================================================
# Get the names of the output layers
def getOutputsNames1(net1):
    # Get the names of all the layers in the network
    layersNames = net1.getLayerNames()
    # Get the names of the output layers, i.e. the layers with unconnected outputs
    return [layersNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net1.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
#====================================================================================
# Draw the predicted bounding box
def drawPred(classId, conf, left, top, right, bottom):
    # Draw a bounding box.
    cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 178, 50), 3)

    label = '%.2f' % conf

    # Get the label for the class name and its confidence
    if classes:
        assert(classId < len(classes))
        label = '%s:%s' % (classes[classId], label)

    #Display the label at the top of the bounding box
    labelSize, baseLine = cv.getTextSize(label, cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
    top = max(top, labelSize[1])
    cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top - round(1.5*labelSize[1])), (left + round(1.5*labelSize[0]), top + baseLine), (255, 255, 255), cv.FILLED)

    cv.putText(frame, label, (left, top), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0,0,0), 1)
#=====================================================================================================================================
def drawPred1(classId, conf, left, top, right, bottom):
    # Draw a bounding box.
    cv.rectangle(crop, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 178, 50), 3)

    label = '%.2f' % conf

    # Get the label for the class name and its confidence
    if classes1:
        assert(classId < len(classes1))
        label = '%s:%s' % (classes1[classId], label)

    #Display the label at the top of the bounding box
    labelSize, baseLine = cv.getTextSize(label, cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
    top = max(top, labelSize[1])
    cv.rectangle(crop, (left, top - round(1.5*labelSize[1])), (left + round(1.5*labelSize[0]), top + baseLine), (255, 255, 255), cv.FILLED)

    cv.putText(crop, label, (left, top), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0,0,0), 1)

# Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence using non-maxima suppression
crop = ''
def postprocess(frame, outs):
    frameHeight = frame.shape[0]
    frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
    # Scan through all the bounding boxes output from the network and keep only the
    # ones with high confidence scores. Assign the box's class label as the class with the highest score.
    classIds = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    global crop

    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            classId = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classId]
            if confidence > confThreshold:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)
                width = int(detection[2] * frameWidth)
                height = int(detection[3] * frameHeight)
                left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                classIds.append(classId)
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                boxes.append([left, top, width, height])
    print('this is: ', classIds, confidence, boxes)
    # Perform non maximum suppression to eliminate redundant overlapping boxes with
    # lower confidences.
    indices = cv.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold)
    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = boxes[i]
        left = box[0]
        top = box[1]
        width = box[2]
        height = box[3]
        drawPred(classIds[i], confidences[i], left, top, left + width, top + height)
        # print(left,top,width,height)
        #координаты y1=top, y2=top+height, x1=left, x2=left+width
        #срез frame по указанным координатам и копирование в папку
        crop = frame[top:top + height+1, left:left + width+1].copy()
        # print("//////////////////////", type(crop))
        cv.imwrite("/DISK/KrisServis/CNN/dark/darknet/detect_yolov3_spp/1.jpg", crop)

    #=======================================================================================================================================================
def post(crop, outs1):
    cropHeight = crop.shape[0]
    cropWidth = crop.shape[1]
    # Scan through all the bounding boxes output from the network and keep only the
    # ones with high confidence scores. Assign the box's class label as the class with the highest score.
    classIds_for_crop = []
    confidences_crop = []
    boxes_crop = []
    for out in outs1:
        # print('this is out: ', out)
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            classId = np.argmax(scores)
            print('scores', classId)
            confidence_crop = scores[classId]
            if confidence_crop > confThreshold:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * cropWidth)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * cropHeight)
                width = int(detection[2] * cropWidth)
                height = int(detection[3] * cropHeight)
                left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                classIds_for_crop.append(classId)
                confidences_crop.append(float(confidence_crop))
                boxes_crop.append([left, top, width, height])
    # Perform non maximum suppression to eliminate redundant overlapping boxes with
    # lower confidences.
    print('all ', confidence_crop, boxes_crop, classIds_for_crop)
    indices = cv.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes_crop, confidences_crop, confThreshold, nmsThreshold)
    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = boxes_crop[i]
        left = box[0]
        top = box[1]
        width = box[2]
        height = box[3]
        drawPred1(classIds_for_crop[i], confidences_crop[i], left, top, left + width, top + height)
        # print('this is: l t w h', left,top,width,height)
# Process inputs
winName = 'Deep learning object detection in OpenCV'
cv.namedWindow(winName, cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)

outputFile = "yolo_out_py.avi"
if (args.image):
    # Open the image file
    if not os.path.isfile(args.image):
        print("Input image file ", args.image, " doesn't exist")
        sys.exit(1)
# =========================================================================================================
    # Подгрузка видео
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(args.image)
    outputFile = args.image[:-4]+'_yolo_out_py.jpg'
elif (args.video):
    # Open the video file
    if not os.path.isfile(args.video):
        print("Input video file ", args.video, " doesn't exist")
        sys.exit(1)
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(args.video)
    outputFile = args.video[:-4]+'_yolo_out_py.avi'
else:
    # Webcam input
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

# Get the video writer initialized to save the output video
if (not args.image):
    vid_writer = cv.VideoWriter(outputFile, cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 30, (round(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),round(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))))

while cv.waitKey(1) < 0:

    # get frame from the video
    hasFrame, frame = cap.read()

    # Stop the program if reached end of video
    if not hasFrame:
        print("Done processing !!!")
        print("Output file is stored as ", outputFile)
        cv.waitKey(3000)
        # Release device
        cap.release()
        break

    # Create a 4D blob from a frame.
    blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1/255, (inpWidth, inpHeight), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)
    # blob1 = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(, 1/255, (inpWidth, inpHeight), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)


    # Sets the input to the network
    net.setInput(blob)
    # net1.setInput(blob1)

    # Runs the forward pass to get output of the output layers
    outs = net.forward(getOutputsNames(net))
    # outs1 = net1.forward(getOutputsNames1(net1))
    # Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence

    postprocess(frame, outs)

    blob1 = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(crop, 1/255, (inpWidth, inpHeight), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)
    # print('this is blob1',blob1)
    net1.setInput(blob1)
    outs1 = net1.forward(getOutputsNames1(net1))
    # print('this is outs1',outs1)
    post(crop, outs1)
    # Put efficiency information. The function getPerfProfile returns the overall time for inference(t) and the timings for each of the layers(in layersTimes)
    t, _ = net.getPerfProfile()
    # t1, _1 = net1.getPerfProfile()

    # label = 'Inference time: %.2f ms' % (t * 1000.0 / cv.getTickFrequency())
    # cv.putText(frame, label, (0, 15), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255))

    # Write the frame with the detection boxes
    if (args.image):
        cv.imwrite(outputFile, crop.astype(np.uint8))
    else:
        vid_writer.write(frame.astype(np.uint8))

    cv.imshow(winName, frame)
    # cv.imshow(winName, crop)
    cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: instead of         `cv.imwrite("/DISK/KrisServis/CNN/dark/darknet/detect_yolov3_spp/1.jpg", crop)` choose an individual name for each cropped image, then you can check whether cropping was performed correctly. then, understand all the code you copied from learnOpenCV and send the cropped image to your second neural network.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying. We know how this code is working, we just checked this code for cropping images. Could you advice how to combine these models? We want to implement the second model to code for detecting. The execution of code gives us only detected plate on image with label.

Comment: my advice is to refactor the code and making both processings more independent from each other. The general way of 1. detection, cropping and 2. sending the cropped images to a classifier or to a subimage detector is ok. I think you can test this out of your application quite well, to see whether the 2nd model can use the cropped images at all.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? any error? you define two different nets so it should work corrctly. Did you debug the code line by line?

Comment: There is no errors when I put image with car, model found license plate then cropped it but second model doesn't work. That's a problem.